# Как реализовать повторную загрузку шрифтов, изображений и запросов после потери связи?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите есть ли готовые решения, или может пример реализации дозагрузки ресурсов на странице, которые не успели загрузится пока был интернет (шрифты и картинки), а так же повторить запросы ajax которые выполнялись уже без интернета?

Нашел на гитхабе Offline.js, однако проблема в том, что он не загружает повторно изображения и шрифты, а выполняет только повторно запросы, которые не смогли выполнится в отсутствие интернета, однако и они выполняются не совсем так как хотелось бы, а точнее после их выполнения не учитывается код из блока jQuery $.post().done(), из-за чего становится их выполнение бессмысленным.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку или наводку на примеры, статьи с реализацией подобного, или может есть библиотека, которая реализует такой функционал!